# How to import a Kotlin script job configuration into TeamCity?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, configuration-as-code

I want to use the settings.kts script in TeamCity to create jobs, instead of manually clicking trough the UI. There is a button, "View as code", which lets me see the empty script of my newly created job, but I cannot paste the content there, the field is read only.
How can I import this settings.kts script?
Please do not suggest to commit it to source control, we are just not there yet, and I am not sure if this is what we want. For now, I just want to save the work of clicking hundred times in the UI to create a new job.